# SQL HELP: How to get the 2 largest values from the table

Tags: sql

I would like to select the top two int values in my table

For example lets say my table looks like this

```
(Name,Int)

(a,1)

(b,2)

(c,2)

(d,5)
```

My result query would return
d, b, and c

I am not sure how i would approach this, any suggestions?

Comment: You'll need to use ranking. Depending on your database system, this may be trivial or sophisticated, if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

2 or 3 values?  Question says both???

```
select top 3 Name
from MyTable
order by IntCol desc
```

Is this homework? [Note: naming a column 'Int' is a very poor choice. Choose something meaningfull]

Comment: its just an example, but i want the two greatest values including their duplicates

Comment: then please make your question clearer and explicitly mention 'duplicates'. You'll probbaly need to use a RANK function.

Comment: @user1436497: *Top two int values* would be simply `5` and `2`. But what you want seems to be *all **rows** containing top two int values*.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on different rdbms.
You can always execute this sql:

```
select name from tab order by int desc limit 3;
```

In rdbms like oracle, it becomes more difficult

```
select * from (
 select name from tab order by int
)
where rownum<=3;
```